# Ubuntu 18.04 AMD GPU drivers - build error during installation

Tags: 18.04, amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

I have 18.04.5 LTS installed (server version).

I need opencl support. I tried installing AMD GPU driver, version 20.40, which is designated to work with this version of Ubuntu:

https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-40

I ran this command to install the driver.

```
./amdgpu-pro-install --headless --opencl=pal,legacy
```

I always get the same result:

```
Building initial module for 4.15.0-135-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-135-generic (x86_64)
```

From the `make.log` file:

```
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147287/build/amd/amdkcl/amdkcl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147287/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_xgmi.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147287/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_csa.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147287/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.c: In function ‘amdgpu_read_platform_bios’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.14.224-1147287/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_bios.c:200:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_platform_rom’; did you mean ‘pci_map_rom’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  bios = pci_platform_rom(adev->pdev, &size);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         pci_map_rom
```

Was anyone successful in installing these drivers, and with which kernel version?
Does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: There's more information in `/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash`. It's a text file, read it with `less`. Move the file to some other directory and rerun to get a current crash dump.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: The 18.04 is a fresh install of Ubuntu. To install the driver, I ran only the command that I wrote above. The only error message is the one that I showed above. The only relevant part of the compilation log is the one I showed above. These are sufficient to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver with the following command:

```
./amdgpu-pro-install --headless --opencl=pal,legacy --no-dkms
```

This will not build the kernel module, and prevent the error from happening.
I seem to be able to use OpenCL with the device now, although I'm not sure what the consequence of not building the kernel module is.